# Why does $n(n-1)(n-2)2^{n-3}+3n(n-1)2^{n-2}+n2^{n-1}=n^2(n+3)2^{n-3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please provide intermediate steps or give a hint to why the following equality is true? Specifically, I'm not seeing how you can get the right-hand side from the left-hand side. Thanks!

$n(n-1)(n-2)2^{n-3}+3n(n-1)2^{n-2}+n2^{n-1}=n^2(n+3)2^{n-3}$

Comment: Remove/cancel the factor $n 2^{n-3}$ from all terms. It's easier to treat it when some clutter has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: divide both sides by $2^{n-3}n$ then multiply out and cancel like terms.